# How to add new uploaded image in assets Manager - GrapesJS?

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading

I have uploaded the Image using php , now how can i add it in assets manager - GrapesJS?
Please write the demo code rather than pasting a link to Assets API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ajax call expects, as the result, a JSON with assets inside data key:

```
{
  data: [
    'https://image/path',
    {type: 'image', src: 'https://image/path', height:350, width:250},
    ..
  ]
}
```